# DJANGO ck-editor

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

In Django CK-EDITOR I am getting a whole black background type  window when trying to upload the image . [image]

How Can I solve this ? Like I cant see anything here . I tried adding different kinds of skins if that works but I cant see any config options .

This is my ckeditor_config

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
     
        'skin': 'moono',
        # # 'skin': 'office2013',
        # 'toolbar_Basic': [
        #     ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
        # ],
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            {'name': 'document', 'items': ['Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates']},
            {'name': 'clipboard', 'items': ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']},
            {'name': 'editing', 'items': ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll']},
            {'name': 'forms',
             'items': ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton',
                       'HiddenField']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'basicstyles',
             'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat']},
            {'name': 'paragraph',
             'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-',
                       'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl',
                       'Language']},
            {'name': 'links', 'items': ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']},
            {'name': 'insert',
             'items': ['Image', 'Youtube','Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'styles', 'items': ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']},
            {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
            {'name': 'tools', 'items': ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks']},
            {'name': 'about', 'items': ['CodeSnippet']},
            {'name': 'about', 'items': ['About']},
            '/',  
            {'name': 'yourcustomtools', 'items': [

                'Preview',
                'Maximize',
            ]},
        ],
        'toolbar': 'Custom',  
        'toolbarGroups': [{ 'name': 'document', 'groups': [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] }],
        'height': 400,
        # 'width': '100%',
        'filebrowserWindowHeight': 725,
        'filebrowserWindowWidth': 940,
        'toolbarCanCollapse': True,
        'mathJaxLib': '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.2-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
        'tabSpaces': 4,
        'extraPlugins': ','.join([
            'uploadimage', 
            'div',
            'autolink',
            'autoembed',
            'embedsemantic',
            'autogrow',
            'devtools',
            'widget',
            'lineutils',
            'clipboard',
            'dialog',
            'dialogui',
            'elementspath',
            'codesnippet',
        ]),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my problem was just because I use Firefox. When you use dark mode firefox adds CSS `color-scheme` to the page

[the release](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/96.0/releasenotes/#note-788916)

Try ckeditor on another browser

Comment: I am using this in google chrome , but still i see this thing .